# Temporary push button power switch

Tags: electrical

I'm building a remote button to flush a toilet and I need a temporary power switch - something that will run 120V for say 3 to 10 seconds....

I have googled extensively and have not found anything...anyone have a solution?

correction, power is 12v - motor I'm using is DC and I have a transformer.

Also, I found what I need: "timed delay relay".

The timed delay relay will power a motor that lifts the flush handle and then shuts off.  Like a piston crank shaft.

I will update with a DIY when/if I finish this.

Comment: So you don't want a momentary switch that's only on when you push it?  You essentially want a 3-10 second timer?

Comment: yes. I would prefer that...however, I just found a simple "auto-flip" switch - like a temporary paddle and I may use that to start.

Comment: Best I know of is a Belkin WeMo switch that can turn off automatically after 1 minute.  You can always build something with basic electrical circuits like a relay and a 555 timer (being very general here).  Link to the paddle switch?

Comment: I'm not sure you're approaching this correctly and not sure having 120V interacting with a plumbing fixture is a good idea.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Have you looked at something like the [Kohler Touchless Toilet Flush Kit](http://www.us.kohler.com/us/catalog/productDetails.jsp?productNumber=1954) to see if it will meet your needs or if you can do something similar to how that works?

Comment: I think I found what I need: google "timed delay relays"

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the timing on one of these:
[image]

and add a double pole switch.

Comment: You need to add a link to the Instructables, or Make, or whatever schematic for this thing.

Comment: Found this on [Think Geek](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/ef0b/), and another one on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Itself-Useless-Box-Machine-Assembled/dp/B00O0W386C/).  "Useless box" seems to be a good search term.

Comment: yes, I like this very much.I was actually planning on using a nautilus gear to lift and drop the plunger.  However, this is an elegant solution though it requires an additional contact switch, but removes the need for the relay. I will mull on both.

Comment: In fact, now that some pencil has been applied to some graph paper, this solution, combined with the nautilus gear the is more elegant.  Nautilus gear lifts the plunger.  Remote switch turns motor on, turning gear, lifting plunger off contact switch. Falling plunger lands on contact switch turning off motor.  Thanks!

Comment: These things always are more entertaining if you can incorporate a live animal into the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

See my edit: "timed delay relay".